# Google Chrome Print Preview of page issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem that I am trying to fix for someone on the below page.

http://www.photographix.co.uk/external/the_dolphin/a-la-carte-menu.php

The problem is that when I attempt to print the page it is on one page only and half of the text disappears. This is on google chrome only (other browsers appear to be working ok which surprises me).

I am using a print style sheet and have tried using page breaks to no avail.

This is how they are printing to each browser, I appreciate each one may be slightly different.
(Need more rep to post all links)
http://www.photographix.co.uk/external/the_dolphin/chrome.pdf

At the moment I am just trying to get the text on chrome to appear on more than one page, I appreciate any help given.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate that. I printed to pdf using chrome version 33

http://www.matthewclittle.com/dolphinclub.pdf

Comment: It stays on page in my print preview aswell, although with no styling. Also, this is not a PHP issue.

Comment: My print preview looks fine as well. I'm using the latest release. Is your browser up to date? Also this may be a printer driver issue.